# Why my bootstrap buttons don't look so good?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm following the set up outlined in the following:

```
http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/
```

However, my buttons don't look too good, here is the `html`:

```
<div><button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Primary</button></div>    
<div><button type="button" class="btn btn-lg  btn-success">Success</button></div>
<div><button type="button" class="btn btn-lg  btn-info">Info</button></div>
<div><button type="button" class="btn btn-lg  btn-warning">Warning</button></div>
<div><button type="button" class="btn btn-lg  btn-danger">Danger</button></div>
```

Here is how they look:

[image: my buttons]

Compare these to the following from:

```
http://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/
```

[image]

Mine just don't look as sleek, what am I missing?
Thanks.

Comment: What browser? What OS?

Comment: Did you include the separate `theme.css`?

Comment: Inspect one of the buttons and see what is going on in the css. If you are not in an unsupported browser, you must be overwriting a gradient (and maybe border) style.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are most likely missing the "bootstrap-theme.min.css" file - it would be helpful if you told us if you were getting console errors.

Comment: That was it!  Thank you!  I use MVC, so I went into my BundleConfig.cs file and added `"~/Content/bootstrap-theme.css"` to the default `bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include` line of code.  I was beginning to worry our users would not click our buttons because they didn't look like buttons.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not set any class to your `<div>` tags, they're interpreted as CSS blocks, their default behaviour.

In order to obtain an inline result you'd better use the `col-lg-*` with * a number between 1 and 12 (On bootstrap 3), which will make them inline elements.

Example :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2"><button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Primary</button></div>    
    <div class="col-lg-2"><button type="button" class="btn btn-lg  btn-success">Success</button></div>
    <div class="col-lg-2"><button type="button" class="btn btn-lg  btn-info">Info</button></div>
    <div class="col-lg-2"><button type="button" class="btn btn-lg  btn-warning">Warning</button></div>
    <div class="col-lg-2"><button type="button" class="btn btn-lg  btn-danger">Danger</button></div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps you !

Answer (score 1):

After:

```
<title>your title</title>
```

You should have"

```
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="../../dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Now Just put this because you are missing this:

```
<!-- Bootstrap theme -->
<!-- Necessary for buttons to look good -->
<link href="../../dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

At a first glance i think it has something to do with the css ,your missing something in the your css build . Try to enter in the dev tool and see what your missing .

Comment: Ha i knew it though my grammar was "Awsome" i knew it :))