# How to show Bootstrap Buttons inline instead of one per line in Wordpress Specifically?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a new Wordpress Website and want to utilize Bootstrap.

However, when I copy the buttons code [Straight from this Bootstrap Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#btn-groups-single), like this:

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
</div>
```

All what I get is a series of buttons shown each one at in a separate line, like this:

[image]

The only way to make them show on the same line is to have the code as one continuous line, like this:

`<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
</div>`

which is very problematic is the application I want to use them for, and also it is not how the Bootstrap documentation show the code.

I tried this code on several of my WordPress sites on the same server. All have the same problem.

Then I copied the same code and pasted it into a simple html file, this time it showed correctly. [You can check the results by clicking here.](https://test.coptic-treasures.com/wp-content/uploads/books/z.html) So it is not a server problem, but also, I tried it in a clean WordPress environment with no other plugins active, and with multiple themes. Still showing the problem.

I found a [similar question here called: Why my bootstrap buttons don't look so good?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23160549/why-my-bootstrap-buttons-dont-look-so-good), where the suggested solution was to add the Bootstrap theme link (although other online resources suggested that this theme is not essential).

So I added a theme called: Cerulean a CDN, like this:

`<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.7/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>`

The only change in results is that the button colors changed, which means that my WordPress installation is reading the theme. However, the problem remains the same.

**This problem differs from the referenced question** as the other question does not depend on Wordpress platform. **Please read the edit section below.**

[image]

So, What could be the cause of such a problem? The workaround that I found (by making the whole code one line) is not a practical solution for me.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**:
It seems that the problem is related to WordPress itself. This is because WordPress adds `<br />` after each line. This `<br />` does not appear to the post creator, however it does appear in the post code afterwards.

Please check these two codes, as suggested by @Andrei Gheorghiu.

Post 1: No Bootstrap CSS or JS sheets:

https://audio.coptic-treasures.com/no-bootstrap/

The buttons appear stacked. [Here is the code on jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/von2jvj2/)

Post 2: Using Bootstrap CSS and JS sheets:

https://audio.coptic-treasures.com/bootstrap/

The buttons appear stacked too. [Here is the code on jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/mtp6pnk3/)

So the question now is how to use the default Bootstrap code with the default WordPress behavior?

**EDIT 2:**

The only solution I found is to alter the defualt WordPress behaviuor by adding this function to the theme's function.php:

`remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );`

Please refer to this [WordPress codex reference.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wpautop/)

This workaround solved the issue and displayed the buttons correctly. However, it makes editing posts problematic. Is there a way to write a function to limit this filter to certain html classes (so I can apply it to the Bootstrap classes)?

Thanks.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you could provide a code snippet of this on something like http://codepen.io I could then give you an answer as to what is overwriting your default css

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why my bootstrap buttons don't look so good?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23160549/why-my-bootstrap-buttons-dont-look-so-good)

Comment: @trickeedickee. Yes I already referenced this question in my question. please check the paragraph "I found a similar..etc". I will create an account on the website you mentioned and let you know. thanks.

Comment: @ Andrei Gheorghiu.Thanks. I did provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example. I explicitly said that I copied the code straight out of the documentation and provided its link. And also I explained that I tested the same code on multiple WP installations, including clean one. I also pasted the exact same code into the Stackoverflow snippet editor, as well as creating a simple html file (which did not show the problem, as I explained). can you please advise what more information is needed? thanks.

Comment: @AtefWagih what I meant was you need to provide a snippet of the code as you are dealing with it. This would include all references to any other stylesheets which may be causing the css to be altered. A similar question will have very different factors effecting its outcome.

Comment: @trickeedickee. Thanks. All the code, including the imported css and js from the CDN are included in the snippet. I can re-paste them in the question if this will help. The point is that I tested this on 3 different WP installations, including one with only one post and 2017 theme. I tested 7 themes in total across the 3 installations. all have the same problem, with or without the Bootstrap theme import.

Comment: @Andrei Gheorghiu. Yes it is not reproduced in the snippet, and also not reproduced in the simple html file I mentioned in my question. That's why I am asking whether there is a link between WordPress and this problem. The only common item between the 3 WP installations I tested on is the WP itself. Neither the snippet nor the simple html are powered by WP.

Comment: Oh, my gosh, I completely misunderstood your question. I thought they are displayed stacked and you are asking how to make them display inline. Here's your answer and sorry for not paying enough attention. Put `btn-group-vertical` class on your parent: `<div class="btn-group btn-group-vertical">`. If you want them behave like blocks, you need to put `btn-block` class on each `.btn`. Read https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/button-group/ for examples and more details and make sure you select the version you're using from the version selector in upper-right corner.

Comment: @Andrei Gheorghiu. You understood it correctly at first. They display stacked and I want to show them inline. Your `vertical` solution fixed them from being stacked to being properly vertical, but i want to show them inline. thanks for the vertical tip anyway, I will use it in other applications.

Comment: In this case you need to create a proper snippet. Note WP is irrelevant, as it adds little to no CSS to frontend. All you need is the (parent) theme CSS and, in some cases, some plugin added CSS. The simplest way to reproduce it is to copy-paste the source of a page inside jsFiddle or codepen. Taken from rightClick>viewSource. Than you can start deleting markup (HTML) that's irrelevant to the issue, ideally keeping structure, so you don't break any selectors. The tedious part is linking all CSS, but most likely you don't need all.

Comment: Make sure you don't lose the behavior while cleaning it up. :)

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu. .Here are the results: definitely the problem is WP related. Plz see this comparison from a clean WP installation. This post has the code **without** the Bootstrap css and js [here](https://jsfiddle.net/von2jvj2/). this other post is **with** them [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mtp6pnk3/). both posts show the buttons one per line. Both codes are tidied up using jsfiddle. it seems that WP automatically add `<br />` after each line. can you please check? thanks

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu. I found the problem and a workaround. please refer to my 2 edits. however, the workaround is not optimum. is there a way to modify this function to limit it to certain classes? I appreciate if you have a look at the 2 edit sections in my questions. thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162619/discussion-between-andrei-gheorghiu-and-atef-wagih).

Answer (score 1):

If you want WordPress not to add `<br>` tags for each `carriage-return` character and `<p>` tags for each group of consecutive `carriage-return` characters you have two options:

- disable the [`wpautop`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop) filter on `the_content`. You can do it globally, using

```php
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
```

...in your `functions.php` or on a post by post basis using [toggle autop](https://wordpress.org/plugins/toggle-wpautop/) plugin (i haven't tested it). Keep in mind this will most likely change how the affected content looks (as it will no longer have `<p>` wrappers and `<br>` tags added to it).

- the second option is to deal with the problem locally, by changing the markup to no longer include `carriage-return` chars:

```html
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="..."
  ><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button
  ><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button
  ><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button></div>
```